# Google Crawler constantly reports ~2-3% errors

Tags: googlebot

For the last year and a half, I have a constant 2-3% error rate while crawling my web site. Types of errors are "Server error: No response".

I've switched ISP, but errors persist. Debugging of application stack didn't give me any hint whatsoever...

I tried "Fetch as Google" - but that works every time without error.

Google offcourse isn't really helpful, it doesn't provide exact links where crawler failed nor does it provide timestamps or something that could help me analyzing logs.

Do you guys have any suggestions how to lower the error rate or troubleshoot this kind of issue? Did any of you had something similar?

Comment: Do you have any data in webserver's error logs? If logging is not disabled, then there should be some useful data.

Comment: What kind of data?

Comment: I mean, does server's error log have any errors registered? Or they are empty? This info should show right direction to start searching.